# How to connect to a DB on windows

Tags: python, sql-server, windows

I have a SQL server 2005 server database on a server and need to conect to it from a client on the same server network, any ideas?

Comment: What are you using?  Is this in a certain application, IDE etc?

Comment: I assume from your python tag you mean the client is written in Python?

Comment: python 25, to biuld a console app on windows 7

Comment: yes is a client written in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pymssql](http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/) library is one option.

Answer (score 0):

see here for the ensemble of database connector:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces

for sql server see here:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server

Answer (score 0):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch 

connection_string = "Provider=SQLNCLI;server=%s;initial catalog=%s;user id=%s;password=%s"%(server,db_name,user,pwd) 

dbConn = Dispatch("ADODB.Connection") 

dbConn.Open( connection_string )
```